# Getting low resolution on coordinates when converting to JSON

Tags: json, xml, geoserver

I'm making a WFS call to a geoServer hosted by the City of Stockholm that shows where it's forbidden to park on certain days.

The original data is shown in XML, but since you can request other data formats in the WFS call - i'm making the call `&outputFormat=application/json`. Then strange stuff is starting to happen:

#### Original lat- and long coords

if you don't ask for any formatting of the coordinates - the result is presented in the format `SWEREF99` and XML format.
If you keep `XML` as the output, but change to the `WGS84` format, the values has a resolution of 6 decimals

`<gml:posList>59.297013 18.019718 59.296889 18.019697</gml:posList>`

#### JSON Output

when you ask the geoserver to convert the data to JSON the result being delivered looks like this:

`[[18.0474,59.2943],[18.0476,59.2942]]`

as you can see the JSON format cuts the all decimals except for the first 4 ones.

> **On spatialreference.org this can be read about the bounds of WGS84:**
> WGS84 Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000

### My question

Does this mean that i can't get a higher resolution on my coordinates if i'm asking for the coordinates in WGS84?
Is there any other WFS request i can make to get the full resolution? Or is it the city of Stockholm that needs to change their settings for the data output?

Comment: Why not ask the IT department of Stockholm about it? They run the servers, they can tell you why their APIs return what they return

Comment: I've talked to them about it - but no one could give me a really clear answer... Their solution was to download a CSV file or just use the XML. Not very helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about why a web service doesn't return the data you would like it to return, and that isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoServer allows the owner of the server to [set the number of decimal digits](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#global-settings) of in JSON & GML outputs. So I would expect you to see the same output from both formats unless they are doing some sort of post-processing on the JSON data.

Depending on what you want to do with the data 4 decimal places should be fine, as discussed in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) it will be accurate to ~10m which is as good as your GPS. If you need better accuracy then you should probably get your data projected into [SWEREF99](http://epsg.io/?q=SWEREF99) which should give you sub-meter accuracy (assuming, of course, it was measured that well).